# A generic C++ library that provides QtConcurrent functionality?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost

[`QtConcurrent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-qtconcurrent.html) is awesome.

I'll let the Qt docs speak for themselves:

> QtConcurrent includes functional programming style APIs for parallel list processing, including a MapReduce and FilterReduce implementation for shared-memory (non-distributed) systems, and classes for managing asynchronous computations in GUI applications.

For instance, you give `QtConcurrent::map()` an iterable sequence and a function that accepts items of the type stored in the sequence, and that function is applied to all the items in the collection. This is done in a multi-threaded manner, with a thread pool equal to the number of logical CPU's on the system.

There are plenty of other function in `QtConcurrent`, like `filter()`, `filteredReduced()` etc. The standard CompSci map/reduce functions and the like.

I'm totally in love with this, but I'm starting work on an OSS project that will not be using the Qt framework. It's a library, and I don't want to force others to depend on such a large framework like Qt. I'm trying to keep external dependencies to a minimum (it's the decent thing to do).

I'm looking for a generic C++ framework that provides the same/similar high-level primitives that `QtConcurrent` does, and that works with STL collections. AFAIK `boost` has nothing like this (I may be wrong though). `boost::thread` is very low-level compared to what I'm looking for (but if the requested lib used `boost::thread` for the low-level work, that would be great).

I know C# has something very similar with their Parallel Extensions so I know this isn't a Qt-only idea.

What do you suggest I use?

Comment: QtConcurrent is cool.  I adapted the Mandelbrot example to use a parallel interface...might interest you: http://hostilefork.com/thinker-qt/

Comment: @Hostile Yes, QtConcurrent is cool. As I've said, I'm using it all the time. I'm just looking for something like it that works with STL collections and without Qt itself.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought the modularity of Qt would mean that you have to use at most only QtCore and QtConcurrent (and not "such a large framework as Qt")?

Comment: @mosfet Yes, but I'd like to avoid linking to QtCore as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [Intel's Threaded Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/), though I haven't used it

As of Oct 2009, it doesn't seem to have map-reduce specifically. But people have expressed interest and suggested they were going to come up with something:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=65053

> "map reduce looks like a simple combination of a filter, a sort, and a reduction but it might need some magic to get it to be efficient"

Comment: I've taken a look at TBB, and it's nice. It doesn't have map/reduce, but it does have a ton of stuff I don't need :). It seems like overkill IMHO. QtConcurrent provides a total of 7 functions (+ overloads and blocking variants) while TBB has ranges, collections, algos, task scheduling, timing, thread local storage and probably the kitchen sink, too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_Concurrent)?  I don't think it provides quite as high-abstraction a layer as `Qt`, but it should be possible to make one as a reasonably thin facade on top of Boost's primitives (indeed, maybe some of the existing [add-ons](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/index.php?directory=Concurrent%20Programming) already provide what you require -- I have to admit I'm not familiar with them in detail, which is why I say "maybe";-).

If you find out that existing add-ons are unsuitable, your facade would be an excellent add-on to contribute to the Boost Vault (or other open-source repo) yourself, "giving back" a useful reusable open-source contribution... I hope this motivates you to do this work if needed!-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using boost. And If there's no lib that does what I'm looking for, I'm prepared to roll my own. But I'd rather not.